# perl shell script escaped replace pattern not working

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have this NOT working issue.

```
echo "aabbccdd" | perl -w -pe "s/(?<Naa>aa)/\g{Naa}-$1/;"
```

it outputs

**Unrecognized escape \g passed through at -e line 1.**

my perl version is "subversion 4 (v5.18.4)"

my bash version is "version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)"

my OS distro is "Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)"

my locale is "C"

how to solve ?

**update:**

how to display same labeled group by number 1 ?

Comment: What version of Perl do you have? Backreferences were introduced in I think Perl 5.14. You can find the Perl version using the command `perl -V`

Comment: Use `"s/(?<Naa>aa)/$+{Naa}/;"`

Comment: Working! BUT why the "+" ?

Comment: You may read about it at https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html, see *Capture Groups* section. *Capture group contents are dynamically scoped and available to you outside the pattern until the end of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever comes first. (See Compound Statements in perlsyn.) You can refer to them by absolute number (using "$1" instead of "\g1" , etc); or by name via the %+ hash, using "$+{name}".*

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `\g{name}` (or `\k<name>`) on the *matching* side of the regular expression. You can use `$+{name}` on the replacement side:

```
echo "aabbaaccdd" | perl -w -pe "s/(?<Naa>aa)(?=bb\g{Naa}).*/$+{Naa}/;"
```

prints out

```
aa
```

This is because named captures are placed in the hash table `%+`.

EDIT: Wiktor Stribiżew beat me to it while I was writing this, in the comments to the question.